# Google charts overflow in jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I am trying to make a google chart to fit in a jquery accordion. But I'm having some annonying scrollbars everywhere, I only wanted it to fit in.
I already tryed to play with the `overflow` property and it doesn't seems to work.
So here is my code :

```
<div id="accordion">
 <h3>Ticket timeline</h3>
 <div id='timelines' class='charts'></div>
 <h3>Ticket booking</h3>
 <div id='booking' class='charts'></div>
</div>
```

And the Css :

```
.charts{
 margin:auto;
 width:100%;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance